# How Do I vary The Stroke Of A Line In Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I'm looking to recreate the line placed above the word "ZARA" in the following example.

[image: example graphic]

Aside from using the Pen tool to get the shape, how can I change the stroke at both ends of the line?

Comment: Which version of Illustrator? CS6 has 'width profiles' and a 'width tool' that makes this very easy (maybe CS5 too?).

Comment: @user568458 the Width tool was indeed implemented at CS5 and called "Beautiful Strokes" at the time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Width Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/painting-fills-strokes.html#create_strokes_with_variable_widths) to vary the stroke of a path in Illustrator.

However...that is now how I would create that shape. It would be easier to just draw to ellipses and use Pathfinder's Minus Front to cut out the shape. To demonstrate, here's what you need to draw:

[image: shape drawn using ellipses]

With both selected, using Minus Front from the Pathfinder pane will produce the final shape.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: any tips on how to get the same distance from the C in care and the R in Zarah to the end of the ellipse?